# How to define a field type for field that contains both chinese and english

Tags: solr

I am now using Solr to index on a field. This field will contain both Chinese and English. At the same time, I need to use tokenizer NGramTokenizerFactory for searching.

Below is the current field type I defined for the field:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general2" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I have to set `minGramSize="1"` to allow searching a single Chinese character. However, this is totally improper for searching an English word.

e.g. If I search "see", it returns "s", "se", "ee", "see", "e"

Therefore, could anyone please tell what is the best way to index a field that contains both Chinese and English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but it's the answer that will actually solve it: Don't use *a single field* to contain *both* chinese and english.

Have one field for english and one field for chinese, indexing to the field matching the language of your input content. You can use the [Language Detection](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) feature in an update processor to let Solr decide which field to put the content into during indexing if you don't know the language when indexing.

Searching is then done across both fields (depending on your query handler, possibly using `qf`), allowing for separate processing of tokens in each language against each field (so that english words doesn't get ngram-ed).

If you have both english and chinese in the same document, process the document to decide the chinese and english parts (for example, iterate over each paragraph and detect language, before indexing to different fields).

Comment: I do have documents including both English and Chinese. Meanwhile, I would return a portion of document content in my program. Therefore, if I separate the Chinese and English words into two fields, I will not be able to retrieve the content. Anyway, thanks for your answer and it did give me some ideas.

Comment: You don't have to fetch the content from the same field that you search against; return the complete document, search against specific fields. If you want highlighting, extract the highlighted portions from the language specific fields.

Comment: Oh.. you are right, that's a good solution. Btw, could you please tell how can I iterate each paragraph and detect languages? It is possible to be done in JAVA?

Comment: Solr uses either [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) or [language-detection](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) - both are Java libraries that you can use yourself to do the detection before indexing. But you don't have to; you can use the langid update processor (as I described in the post), as long as you're able to split the content into paragraphs yourself - each paragraph will then get run through the langid feature and indexed to the correct field.