# Multiple languages in same core in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am implementing Solr in e-commerce site. Now, as there are multiple languages supported in e-commerce site I just wanted to know how can I manage multiple languages in single solr core? I have red about Multiple language in one field. Can anyone please suggest how can I index and query for multiple languages in one field? Any example?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a field type for field that contains both chinese and english](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347429/how-to-define-a-field-type-for-field-that-contains-both-chinese-and-english)

Answer (score 0):

You could have multiple languages in a single field. It will of course 'damage' your frequency vectors and term frequency but if you query using a language specific filter query, say fq:en, then the term frequency will be calibrated to only that.

I would anyways suggest you to use common fields to anything that is not language related (id, category, quantity, etc) but the description and titles you could save in their own fields like 'description_en', 'title_en'.

For the language specific methods you could define specific language analyzers to optimize search and indexing efficiency, take a look at https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis.

Then to access those fields you could define which field to index/query depending on the user language or the store country.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been discussed several times in details on the SolrUser mailing list. There is no simple solution, it all depends on the tradeoffs. The mailing list is not visible on Google as much as it should be, but you could [search it with specialized interface](http://search-lucene.com/?q=&fc_project=Solr&fc_type=mail%20_hash_%20user).

But the other options is to also index languages separately and then use eDisMax to search all of the variants. I have [an example](https://github.com/arafalov/solr-indexing-book/tree/master/published/languages) (from my book) on GitHub.